# How to set run arguments when using Ansible to deploy docker?

Tags: docker, ansible

When using ansible to deploy docker, how do you set the ARGs? That's the ARGs in the following docker command

```
docker create  --name my_container my_image ARGS
```

I tried to set the ARGS in the docker: command variable but it wasn't picked up. 
What's the correct way to set the run ARGS? Here is what I tried

```
- name: deploy docker image
  sudo: yes
  docker:
    image: "{{ docker_image_name }}:{{ docker_image_version }}"
    state: reloaded
    name: "{{ docker_container_name }}"
    command: "{{ docker_args }}"
```

in my group vars I have something like

```
my_hosts:vars
  docker_args="-Dconfig=qa.conf"
```

my docker file has an entry point

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/my_application"]
```

Comment: Please, share what you've tried

Comment: what arguments you want to pass? share what you've tried..

Comment: I updated the question with the example, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the `shell` module.

We tried using the `docker` and `docker_image` modules a while back, and ran into issues. Docker has been moving so quickly that we simply fell back to using the `shell` module.